# Why does pushing to private, secured docker registry fail?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-mac

I would like to run a private, secure, authenticated docker registry on a self healing AWS ECS cluster. The cluster setup is done and works properly, but I struggled getting the `registry:latest` running. The problem was, that every time I push an image, pushing the blobs fails, and goes into a retry cycle unless I get a timeout.

To make sure, that my ECS setup isn’t the blocker, I tried to setup everything locally using Docker4Mac 1.12.0-a.

First, the very basic setup works. I created my own version of the registry image, where there I put my TLS certificate bundle and key as well as the necessary `htpasswd` file directly into the image. [I know, this is insecure, I just do that for the testing purpose]. So here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM registry:latest

COPY htpasswd /etc/docker
COPY server_bundle.pem /etc/docker
COPY server_key.pem /etc/docker
```

`server_bundle.pem` has a **wildcard certificate** for my domain `mydomain.com` (CN=*.mydomain.com) as the first one, followed by the intermediate CA certificates, so clients should be happy. My `htpasswd` file was created using the recommended approach:

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn heyitsme mysupersecurepassword > htpasswd
```

I build my image:

```
docker build -t heyitsme/registry .
```

and afterwards I run a very basic version w/o TLS and authentication:

```
docker run --restart=always -p 5000:5000 heyitsme/registry
```

and I can actually pull, tag and re-push an image:

```
docker pull alpine
docker tag alpine localhost:5000/alpine
docker push localhost:5000/alpine
```

This works. Next I make TLS and basic auth work via environment variables:

```
docker run -h registry.mydomain.com --name registry --restart=always -p 5000:5000 \ 
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST=http://registry.mydomain.com:5000 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/docker/server_bundle.pem \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/etc/docker/server_key.pem \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry-Realm \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/etc/docker/htpasswd heyitsme/registry
```

For the time being I create an entry in `/etc/hosts` which says:

```
127.0.0.1 registry.mydomain.com
```

And then I login:

```
docker login registry.mydomain.com:5000
Username: heyitsme
Password: ***********
Login Succeeded
```

So now, let’s tag and push the image here:

```
docker tag alpine registry.mydomain.com:5000/alpine
docker push registry.mydomain.com:5000/alpine

The push refers to a repository [registry.mydomain.com:5000/alpine]
4fe15f8d0ae6: Retrying in 4 seconds
```

What happens is, that the docker clients tries to push fragments and fails. Then it retries and fails again until I get a timeout. So next check, whether the `V2` API works properly:

```
curl -i -XGET https://registry.mydomain.com:5000/v2/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Registry-Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:06:04 GMT
Content-Length: 87

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

Ok, as expected. So let’s authenticate next time:

```
curl -i -XGET https://heyitsme:mysupersecretpassword@registry.mydomain.com:5000/v2/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 10:06:16 GMT

{}%
```

Works. But pushing still fails.

The logs say:

```
time="2016-09-15T10:24:34Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: basic authentication challenge for realm \"Registry-Realm\": invalid authorization credential" go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host="registry.mydomain.com:5000" http.request.id=6d2ec080-6824-4bf7-aac2-5af31db44877 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:40878" http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.0 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/8eab29e kernel/4.4.15-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.0 \\(darwin\\))" instance.id=be3a8877-de64-4574-b47a-70ab036e7b79 version=v2.5.1
172.17.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2016:10:24:34 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/1.12.0 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/8eab29e kernel/4.4.15-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.0 \\(darwin\\))"
time="2016-09-15T10:24:34Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host="registry.mydomain.com:5000" http.request.id=8f81b455-d592-431d-b67d-0bc34155ddbf http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:40882" http.request.uri="/v2/alpine/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.0 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/8eab29e kernel/4.4.15-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.0 \\(darwin\\))" http.response.duration=30.515131ms http.response.status=202 http.response.written=0 instance.id=be3a8877-de64-4574-b47a-70ab036e7b79 version=v2.5.1
172.17.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2016:10:24:34 +0000] "POST /v2/alpine/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0 "" "docker/1.12.0 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/8eab29e kernel/4.4.15-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.0 \\(darwin\\))"
2016/09/15 10:24:34 http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:40886: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I also tested different versions of the original `registry` image, especially several versions above `2`. All yield the same error. If someone could help me on that issue, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 11):

Solved:

```
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST=https://registry.mydomain.com:5000 \
```

as environment variable did the tick. Just the prior use of `http` instead `https` made the connection fail.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to access it directly via its IP. Very frustrating that it only checks the host headers at the push stage. (As in I can login fine via IP)

Comment: Lost two days (and nights) for searching the solution, but eventually found it here. Thanks. I have defined REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST but without port. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: that was so simple.... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot, it's working now!

I added the variable in my kubernetes deployment manifest:

```
(...)
      - env:
        - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_HOST
          value: "https://registry.k8sprod.acme.domain:443"
(...)
```

For those who use nginx ingress in front, you have to set extra attribute in your ingress manifest file if you have push size errors:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-registry
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "8192m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "10"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kube-registry
    app: kube-registry
spec:
  rules:
    - host: registry.k8sprod.acme.domain
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: svc-kube-registry
            servicePort: 5000
```